# yas-snippet-dirs is not a directory

Tags: emacs

I've just installed yasnippet, and added the following to my `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
          "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

However, on startup, I get the following error from Emacs:

```
 Check your `yas-snippet-dirs': ~/.emacs.d/snippets is not a directory
```

Now, I've checked that variable, and it's defined as something called `top-level-dirs` in `yasnippet.el`. In my case, `snippets` is located in `~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet`, rather than directly in `~/.emacs.d/` as the program seems to expect. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have or use yasnippets. But it sounds like the error message is trying to tell you that the value of that variable should be an existing directory but is not.

Is that variable a user option? IOW, if you do `C-h v yas-snippet-dirs` does buffer `*Help*` have a link to customize the variable value? If so, follow that link and customize the value to `~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet/` (or whatever the correct directory is).

If the variable is not a user option, try setting it in your init file anyway, using `(setq yas-snippet-dirs "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet/")`.

Comment: My setup does not have the trailing forward-slash -- will that make a difference?  I modified the source as follows:  `(defcustom yas-snippet-dirs (list "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.snippets") . . .`

Comment: @lawlist: Again, I know nothing about yasnippets. Why modify the source code? Sorry, I don't follow. It sounds like the OP just needs to check whether the variable value is the name of an existing directory. If he needs to experiment with adding or removing `/' from the end of the value, he can do that. Changing a `defcustom` is rarely a good idea, if only because of load/eval order problems: you then need to ensure that your `defcustom` is eval'd first etc.

Comment: For a few of the libraries that I plan on using for years to come, I have taken over the source code entirely and made my own revisions.  For those libraries that I have completely taken over (e.g., lawlist-org-mode, lawlist-calculator-mode, lawlist-calendar-mode, etc.), I have chosen to set the default values by modifying the `defcustom` settings.  It's not something that I would suggest as a sample answer, but makes sense to me for my own setup.  I wasn't sure whether using `list` is necessary when using `yas-snippet-dirs`, so I put that in my comment too just in case it might be important.

Comment: @Drew I have tried to setting the folder but I keep getting following error: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp "~/.emacs.d/snippets/")
  member("/home/alper/snippets" "~/.emacs.d/snippets/")` , full error log: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/df3e4b211f25d59eb6de7639dc1ff826